# Linking libraries to CMake (MSVC) in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I am doing project using SDL2 library. It works on Ubuntu, but after long time I am unable to compile it on for Windows. I am using Qt creator as IDE and tried lot of solutions found on internet. Currently, my IDE detects files, but I can't build it, because every function I have used in my application (even those I wrote myself and main) throw up error `LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ...` and when I want to see, where is problem, so I click on error, it just write `File not found: FILE.cpp.obj`.

My current **CMakeLists.txt** looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(Joystick)
set(SDL2_LIBRARIES D:/Projects/Libs/SDL2-2.0.9/lib/x64/)
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR D:/Projects/Libs/SDL2-2.0.9/include)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp" "JoystickController.cpp" "JoystickController.h" "UDPSender.cpp" "UDPSender.h" "JoystickErrors.h")

include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

I don't have much experience with CMake, because I am using qmake everytime when building application, but this time I am forced to use CMake. This file is made out of internet tutorials, so I really can't tell, if it's good or wrong, but it's only way my IDE would load header files.

Wierd is, that on Linux system I used `#include <SDL/...h>`, but on Windows, I am using only `#include <...h>`, because with first method it doesn't find file.

Where am I doing mistake? What is correct way to add this library to CMakeList?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `set(SDL2_LIBRARIES D:/Projects/Libs/SDL2-2.0.9/lib/x64/)` is not a list of libraries. You probably should use `find_package` instead.

Comment: There is a module for finding SDL: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindSDL.html

Comment: @arrowd I can't use it on Windows, because Windows hierarchy

Comment: @arrowd no need for the module, SDL export their target correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're building SDL from source, you can easily import SDL's targets.

For building SDL:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:/local/ ..
cmake --build . --target install
```

Then, in your project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(Joystick)

add_executable(Joystick main.cpp JoystickController.cpp UDPSender.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Joystick PUBLIC SDL2:SDL2)
```

Then when invoking CMake, specify your prefix for your libraries:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=c:/local/ ..
```

On linux, the default prefix will find any system libraries.